# how to manage new FrameLayout in the second activity based onClicklistener in fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm doing android project implementing fragment and get a trouble.
here is the trouble story:

I've created Main activity which is hold the fragment using Fragment Layout. I do this because i want to implement navigation menu using drawer menu. It works fine for all these steps.

here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private NavigationView navigationView;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.layout_drawer);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer,toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new Main_fragment()).commit();
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.home);
    }
}
```

it works fine until here.

Then in the fragment activity, i triggered a Textview and invoke new activity. i do that because i want to make a new Place Holder for the fragments and put different Drawer Menu.

her is the code:

```
public class Main_fragment extends Fragment{
TextView t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment,container,false);
    //define buttons
    t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    t3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt3);
    t4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt4);
    t5 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt5);
    t6 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt6);
    t7 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt7);


    t1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //intent to the second activity
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Social_Container.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    t2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Social_Container.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    t3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Social_Container.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    t4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Social_Container.class);
            startActivity(i);

            /**
            //this code just for trial fragment
            FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fr.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment_Pengurusan());
            fr.commit();
            **/
        }
    });
    t5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Social_Container.class);
            startActivity(i);

            /**
            FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fr.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment_Politic());
            fr.commit();
            **/
        }
    });
    t6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Social_Container.class);
            startActivity(i);

            /**
            FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fr.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment_Industri());
            fr.commit();
            **/
        }
    });
    t7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Social_Container.class);
            startActivity(i);

            /**
            FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fr.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment_Awam());
            fr.commit();
            **/
        }
    });

    return v;
  }
}
```

the question is, how can i triggered the fragment activity to be set on the second class place holder (FrameLayout) based onCLick that i set on the Textview that i attached in the last Fragment activity which is inside the Main Activity?

note: I didn't set anything inside the second class yet. I just want to know how to invoke the fragment inside that Second Class based onClickListener from TextView there.

Comment: kodak, I could not understand your question?? you want to call `fragment` from other `fragment`??

Comment: @RakeshKumar yes sir. using onClickListener. 1 fragment in Main Activity, start Second Activity (not a fragment) based on Click Textview, and set the framelayout inside this second activity to call a fragment. I am sorry if its not clear :(

Comment: @RakeshKumar like this sir, i have 2 classes inside the project as container for fragments. in the first class, the fragment has 7 textview that can be click. when i click each textview, it will start Second class. what i want is, in the second class, it has FrameLayout to put the fragment based on click the textview. if i click tv1, second class start and fragment_tv1 start. if i click tv2, second class start and fragment_tv2 start. im not really good at explaining sir. thanks for the reply

Comment: kodak, You want to start an `Activity` or `fragment` and where exactly you are getting issue??

Comment: @RakeshKumar both sir